# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE refuses to update

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

Having some troubles with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MySQL. Below is the query im trying to run.

```
INSERT INTO `Overall` ( `rsn` , `starting_xp` , `starting_lvl` ) VALUES ( 'iWader' , '195843626' , '2281' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `current_xp` = '195843626' AND `current_lvl` = '2281'
```

- It inserts fine, but when there is a duplicate it doesnt update, and doesnt throw any errors.
- Running the query through PMA returns no error and doesnt update
- Removing the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE section returns a duplicate key error

This is the structure of my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `overall` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rsn` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `starting_xp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `starting_lvl` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `current_xp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `current_lvl` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rsn` (`rsn`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you should not need to use `and` with the fields, use  `,` instead.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `current_xp` = '195843626', `current_lvl` = '2281'
```

Comment: @Michael, sorry, fixed it, I am going to bed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `Overall` ( `rsn` , `starting_xp` , `starting_lvl` ) VALUES ( 'iWader' , '195843626' , '2281' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `current_xp` = '195843626', `current_lvl` = '2281';
```

The `AND` in your `UPDATE` clause is wrong. The `AND` is used in **boolean expressions** like "is foo true `AND` bar true?"
Here you want to update column current_xp, current_lvl.

Comment: Please provide an explanation along with your solution (which is correct) -- an upvote-worthy answer is never just a line of code with _try this_.

Comment: @Michael I totally agree and edited my answer, but sometimes the learn effect might be higher if you have to search for the error yourself. Instead of just thinking "k, it's the AND" you go over the whole problem again and ... you get the point. Just thinking...